# (VB) Pass variable to Report Parameter

Tags: vb.net

have a
[Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQGt0.png) in Report

How can I pass a variable in real time to the Report Parameter?

Comment: What type of report is this?

Comment: @OneFineDay .rdlc

Comment: Sorry not familiar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add them via the `ReportParameter` class.

See here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337089%28v=sql.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I still can not solve it, have report ReportVentas.rdlc and parameter Cabecera

Comment: How are you using the RDLC, report viewer control?

Comment: ready,
First 
'Create a report parameter for the sales order number 
        Dim rpSalesOrderNumber As New ReportParameter()
        rpSalesOrderNumber.Name = "Name Parameter"
        rpSalesOrderNumber.Values.Add("Text")

        'Set the report parameters for the report
        Dim parameters() As ReportParameter = {rpSalesOrderNumber}
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters)

Comment: I assume you renamed the .name correctly, and refreshed the report after this with .RefreshReport?